# Merging two JSON by adding their value

Tags: php, merge

I am trying to merge two JSON , but instead of overwriting the value if it is found, I want to ADD the value if it is found For exemple, assuming I have tje following three values.

```
$a = "[{"base":"10","touch":true,"flatfooted":true}]"
$b = "[{"natural armor":"2","touch":false,"flatfooted":true}]"
$c = "[{"natural armor":"3","touch":false,"flatfooted":true}]"
```

I would like to get the following result:

```
"[{"base":"10","touch":true,"flatfooted":true},{"natural armor":"5","touch":false,"flatfooted":true}]"
```

But I'm getting lost in the way.

Thank you for the help.

Also, asking in advance to avoid asking in another question: How can I turn every JSON object into a different array?

Assuming the result JSON, something like

```
$final[0]['base'] = 10,
$final[0]['touch'] = true,
$final[0]['flatfooted'] = true,
$final[1]['natural armor'] = 5,
$final[1]['touch'] = false,
$final[1]['flatfooted'] = true
```

Comment: Do you have spesific keys you want to sum (like `natural_armor`) or every field that is numeric?

Comment: This could be a really complex program to write because the amount of json arrays is, I assume variable. We need to compare all keys of the jsons and make sure they have the same name. We also need to know if the boolean values of all keys are the same value (truthy or falsy) and finally sum the numeric values. I gave you a start (check my answer) can't finish it because I have to leave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start, I can't finish it because I have to leave. Good luck!

```
<?php

$a = '[{"base":"10","touch":true,"flatfooted":true}]';
$b = '[{"natural armor":"2","touch":false,"flatfooted":true}]';
$c = '[{"natural armor":"3","touch":false,"flatfooted":true}]';

//Decode values to arrays and get first item.
$a = json_decode($a, true)[0];
$b = json_decode($b, true)[0];
$c = json_decode($c, true)[0];

//Put them all in a array
$abc = [$a, $b, $c];


//Compare keys of all arrays, and put the ones with no diffs in a array
$noDiff = [];
foreach ($abc as $idx => $character) {
    //Skip first because we use it in the foreach
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($abc); $i++) {
        $diff = array_diff_key($character, $abc[$i]);
        if (empty($diff)) {
            $noDiff[] = $character;
            $noDiff[] = $abc[$i];
        }
    }

    //Remove item from $abc and reset index keys 
    array_splice($abc, $idx, 1);
}

//$noDiff will now contain array $b and $c and we know they both have the same keys.
//We need to be sure natural armor contains numeric values and that touch and flatfooted
//have both the same boolean value.
$merged = [];
$canCombine = true;
foreach ($noDiff[0] as $key => $value) {
    if (!is_numeric($value) || is_numeric($noDiff[1][$key]) {
        $canCombine = false;    
    } else {

    }
}


echo "<pre>";
var_dump(
    $noDiff
);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score -1):

You can turn any JSON string into an array using:

```
$result = json_decode($jsonString,true) ;
```

If you want each JSON string to end up as a separate element of an array you can use:

```
$final[] = json_decode($jsonString,true) ;
```

So, in your case you could use:

```
$final[] = json_decode($a,true) ;
$final[] = json_decode($b,true) ;
$final[] = json_decode($c,true) ;
```

Though I would recommend a loop in case you don't always have three (e.g., $a, $b & $c).

You should always check json_last_error() after each json_decode() to make sure you didn't generate an error.

Answer (score -1):

Since JSON is serialized data, you need to parse the two json objects you need to merge, then add the result of any fields, then you can update the values of one of your original json objects and serialize the data.

I haven't used PHP before, but here is an article I found on parsing json objects in PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

1) Same AC bonuses DO NOT stack. That means you can't add two natural armors for one unit. You can however do (base + dexterity + natural + size + armor + shield)

2) Why are "touch" and "flat footed" booleans? You just add different subsets of AC

touch = base + dexterity + natural + size

flat footed = base + armor + shield

3) In case you are indeed talking about DnD, I hope you want to make a tool for yourself and your friends to use, cause you can't just publish a tool for DnD, it's copyrighted.

Comment: it is for pathfinder, not DnD, and it is to apply templates to existing creatures. Thus, the exact wording of these template is "increase the natural armor of the creature by X" rather than "the creature gain a natural armor of X". Also, since in pathfinder there area about 10 types of sub-AC (natural, deflection, dodge, magic, enhancement, armor, shield,...) and some of them apply to touch and/or flat footed, and that some creature have specific abilities that says "This creature's natural armor also apply to touch", I'm trying to be as inclusive as possible.

Comment: Anyways, if you really expect to see a helping answer, you need to give more info as to what your input cases are. Like, what does each array represent? Is one the base stats and the rest come to add to it? Will you have many base and additive arrays come at once? Are the same fields that have boolean values always going to have the same value? What happens if they don't, how do you combine boolean? Also I believe that if you 're going for a pathfinder tool without being able to solve this, you will not succeed in creating the tool.

Comment: Well, I managed to convince my teacher to make it my yearly school project. So I don't really have a choice about succeeding. My only regret is that I should have thought more about the way I store these data. I asked my teacher too soon, before thinking about using my DB relations to store, and he said I could try and store it in JSON. Made it a lot harder on myself with that.

Thanks for the heads up, I'll try to keep it in mind next time I ask something.